# Recovery HD tries to delete itself

Tags: macos, disk-utility, partition, recovery-hd

My configuration of Mavericks-Ubuntu-Windows has gone nuts, so I deleted the windows partition and rebooted to Recovery HD to try and reformat the whole HD. Recovery HD at first appeared in disk utility, so I've done this trick `-asr adjust --target /dev/disk0s3 -settype "Apple_Boot"` but I still suspect its trying to delete itself because when I try to repartition the HD to 1 partition there's an error of "Couldn't unmount disk".
How can I trace this error? Or how can I get Recovery HD to not try and delete itself?
Thanks!

Comment: So you are trying to reformat the HD on which the Recovery resides?

Answer (score 1):

Did a full format and install from internet recovery (⌘+R)- worked perfectly!

Answer (score -1):

If I understand correctly, the issue is that Disk Utility can't modify partition tables that contain linux partitions.  You may be able to make the change with gparted from a linux rescue disk but that has other limitations I don't recall.